# Partition not working in mongodb spark read in java connector

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, partition

I was trying to read data using MongoDb spark connector, and want to partition the dataset on a key, reading from mongoD standalone instance. I was looking at the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/java/read-from-mongodb) of mongoDb spark, and it mentions of various partitioner classes. I was trying to use `MongoSamplePartitioner` class but it only reads on just 1 partition. `MongoPaginateByCountPartitioner` class as well partitions to a fixed 66 partitions. This is even when I am configuring "samplesPerPartition" and "numberOfPartitions" in both of these cases respectively. I need to use readConfig created via a map. My code:

```java
SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("sampleRecords")
    .config("spark.driver.host", "2g")
    .config("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1")
    .master("local[4]").getOrCreate();
Map<String, String> readOverrides = new HashMap<>();
readOverrides.put("uri", "mongodb://mongo-root:password@127.0.0.1:27017/importedDb.myNewCollection?authSource=admin");
readOverrides.put("numberOfPartitions", "16");
readOverrides.put("partitioner", "MongoPaginateByCountPartitioner");
ReadConfig readConfig = ReadConfig.create(readOverrides);
JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());
Dataset<Row> dataset = MongoSpark.load(jsc, readConfig).toDF();
    
System.out.println(dataset.count()); //24576        
System.out.println(dataset.rdd().getNumPartitions()); //66
```

Using sample partitioner returns 1 partition everytime
Am I missing something here? Please help.

PS - I am reading 24576 records, mongoD version v4.0.10, mongo spark connector 2.3.1, java 8

Edit:
I got it to work, needed to give properties like so partitionerOptions.samplesPerPartition in the map. But I am still facing issue,  partitionerOptions.samplesPerPartition : "1000", in MongoSamplePartitioner only returns 1 partition. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Number of Partitions can be configured for MongoPaginateByCountPartitioner.

Supposing that we need to configure the target number of partitions to 16...
Please add partitionerOptions.numberOfPartitions -> 16 in the properties rather than only numberOfPartitions -> 16.